# Simplifying expression with ceil

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I simplify the following? $\lceil \frac{x}{\lceil \frac{x}{y} \rceil}\rceil$
I'm dealing with partitioning data for processing, where x is the total input size and y is the maximum chunk size per processing batch job, and I want to keep the chunks as even as possible. The above gives me the actual chunk size to use. For example, with a total size of 605 and maximum specified at 500, I launch two jobs of sizes 303 and 302 respectively. But it seems to me there should be a more concise way to compute this than doing, say if it were Python, `math.ceil(x/math.ceil(x/y))`. Ran it by wolframalpha but it wouldn't simplify it, so my next stop is here.

Comment: There is a ceiling function in WolframAlpha. Did you use it?

Comment: Yes I used it, I wrote the same expression in it

Comment: I just entered ceiling(605/ceiling(605/500)) in WolframAlpha and it gave me 303.

Comment: I don't think you can get much simpler than the expression given (except when $y=ax$ then its value is $y$) but for $x=ay+b$ with $0<b<y$ then the value is $y-\lceil\frac{y-b}{a+1}\rceil$ and the ceil part has no further simplification...

Comment: @MathLover obviously I am talking about simplifying the symbolic expression, not one with actual numbers. The title is "simplifying expression", not "calculating"

Comment: @zwim thanks. If you post this as an answer I will accept it

Comment: From mathematical point of view I agree there is probably not much you can do, but from programming perspective it is certainly better to avoid floating point calculations (here the non-integer division before it gets passed into the ceil function). You can avoid this by converting ceil to floor (for positive values) which is natively implemented on integers in many programming languages. For example in Python 3 `(x-1)//((x-1)//y+1)+1`, in C `(x-1)/((x-1)/y+1)+1`, etc... Assuming the arguments are positive integers.

Comment: @Sil the gain is negligible compared to the 605 wide loop that follows, doesn't worth obfuscating the calculation. But the idea is nice, so why using ceil at all, maybe just $x/(x/y)$ in integer division is well enough.

Comment: @zwim That would give slightly different result though. The aim of the above is not to gain anything in performance (indeed the gain would be negligible), the idea is to avoid floating point errors and limitations, which is sort of rule of thumb in programming - always stay in integer types as long as you can. Simple example in Python, try $x=y=10^{30}$, floating point version above will give wrong result, integer will be just fine. (of course in practice you might say such numbers are rare, unfortunately these issues find sneaky ways to appear so it might be better to avoid them altogether)

Comment: ok but the idea is dividing in chunks, and anyway the last chunk is the remaining, so if there is no strong restriction on chunks boundaries (thus "wrong" calculation is meaningless), we might as well go for slightly smaller chunks and use the simpler form.

Comment: @zwim I see what you mean, yea changing the original formula altogether would be intersting option to simplify it :)